# How can i move ML model to my server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

i create a new ML model on amazon and i want to move it to my website 
to my server to make question/answer .
can you please guide me and give me the details of doing this?
am really new in this thing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't export your aws ml model.

https://aws.amazon.com/aml/faqs/

> Q: Can I export my models out of Amazon Machine Learning?
>
> No.

Comment: How about taking server sanpchot? is that possible?

Comment: I want to move it to my website for questions/answers . to avoid Amazon charging .

Comment: Or is there any api which i can use to relate it to my website .
for example i created a ML model for questions/answers . is there any way that i can create a page in my website where the users submit their questions and get the reply from ML on that page?